# Why image.getRGB(x,y) returns white at some points?

Tags: java, swing, colors, pixel

I am working on a school project with swing-Java. I am trying to draw image with `drawRect(x,y,width,height)` method (later I will do changes to pixels, that's why I need to draw pixels one-by-one). So, I have written this code:

```
private void drawImage(Graphics graphics) {
    
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    
    for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
        for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
            int color = image.getRGB(w, h);             
            graphics.setColor(new Color(color));
            graphics.drawRect(w, h, 1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image: 1]

As you can see, some pixels are drawn with white color. But when I use this code,

```
graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
```

Image is drawn as it should:

[image: 2]

Why `image.getRGB(x,y)` returns white color at some points? What am I missing here?

Comment: Is it actually that `getRGB` is returning white, or is it just a result of using `drawRect` that way?

Comment: Instead of drawing thousands of tiny rectangles, use the image setRGB method.  When you're done manipulating the pixels, draw the entire image.

Comment: @khelwood Problem is with `getRGB`. It doesn't return white, but returns pretty close value to white

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, thank you, sir. It works and will use it. But still, I would like to know why `getRGB` returns wrong value?

Comment: What value exactly does getRGB return for those pixels?

Comment: @tgdavies  some of them: `java.awt.Color[r=253,g=251,b=254]
java.awt.Color[r=252,g=250,b=253]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=254,b=255]`

Comment: How is your image created?

Comment: @Tuqay I don't think getRGB() returns the wrong value.  Instead of drawRect(), which is used to draw a border around the rectangle, try using `fillRect(...)`.

Comment: @tgdavies, I just downloaded it from google. Nothing special about it as far as I know.

Comment: @camickr , `fillRect(...)` works perfectly, thank you. But I am sure that, `getRGB(...)` returns white color at some points

Comment: @Tuqay you just said it works perfectly. So that implies it will return white when the actual color is white. It won't return white randomly.

Comment: @camickr , it doesn't return white randomly, it follows some pattern. And I don't still get it

Comment: If fillRect is producing the right picture, I think that's good evidence that getRGB is returning the correct colours. If you started with a black background, and used drawRect again, I bet you'd see black spots.